# selenium 2 switch window back to the initial window

Tags: windows, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Using the webdriver I have switched the focus to a popup window

```
driver.switchTo().window("SystemAdmin");
```

However I wish to switch back to the initial window which does not have a name. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// get current window
String mainWindowHandle = webDriver.getWindowHandles().iterator().next();
// do what you want in other window
// ...
// switch back
webDriver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```